# Accessing thread in service

Tags: android, service

i have client-server app, I'm managing connections with Threads and handlers inside app, but maintaining synchronization between activities is quite hard, i though to make service that runs in background and contains thread. 
In main activities i want just to get handler to that thread in service and put task by Handler.post(Runnable) method. Is it possible, and how to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you can create service, run the thread inside, and create Handler for it. Then bind the service in activities and get the reference to the handler.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample so i should use something like that? And than i will be able to use public members/methods of my service? Since activities in android are opened on stack, as long as one activity will be bound to service, service will exist?

Comment: Yes, you can use that tutorial. On service connection you will get access to the binder of the service, and what fields/method it has to provide depends on you, as well as you can provide access to the handler field, and in the end use it in each activity.

Comment: Seems i still have little problem. When i try to bind service in second activity, ServiceConnection isn't event executing. My service in new activity is null.

Comment: `bindService(new Intent(Binding.this, LocalService.class), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);` did you do this? I think it's not relative question to the topic. Did you declare a service in AndroidManifest.xml? Did you implemented onBind method in your service? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onBind(android.content.Intent) Does it return null? If so, then of course the connection won't be called.

Comment: bindService returns true, i have done anything you pointed, and my service is similar to that from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample in every activity i`m binding service, and create new ServiceConnection  I just wanted to avoid adding more questions:)